# Convert colored line in Bitmap image to System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: vb.net, image, colors, extract, lines

is there any way to convert a colored lines in a picture (say Path Lines in Google Earth, colored red [image]) into lines of Drawable objects (System.Drawing.Graphics)? If there is no direct way, please point me to the right directions on how to do this?

Basically I want to convert those 3 red lines in the image into 3 red line objects in VB.NET through code. Thanks.

Comment: There are no line objects in VB.NET. There are no drawable objects. The `System.Drawing.Graphics` class simply specifies pixels to be drawn onto an canvas. Please describe what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it. Are you trying to create lines that can be moved and/or erased? Something else? If you are displaying an `Image` in a `PictureBox` then you can draw on the `PictureBox` rather than the `Image`, thus enabling you to change what is drawn. Once you draw on an `Image` though, that drawing is part of the `Image`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I want to create 3 individual red selectable line objects in a VB.NET Form from that image. How do I achieve that? I was thinking of extracting 1 color from the picture and then work from there. But how?

Comment: What do you intend to do with them once selected?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have this code where it measures angle of the line (for example: if it's a straight vertical line, The angle is 0 / 360 degrees, if it's straight horizontal line, it's 90 / 180 degrees). It's for a project of mine basically.

Comment: It seems, then, that the question here is how to select a region of an image by colour, so that's what you should research. Without a specific attempt and a specific issue, the question is too general for SO. "How do I do X?" questions aren't really appropriate here. That's not to say that they aren't legitimate questions, but this site is for specific issues, not general ones like that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am sorry for not being more detailed. With all being said, is there a way to do so that you personally know of?